# Getting "The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Tags: build, reference, tfs, compiler-errors

I need some help - I have already searched for an answer to my issue on this forum and many others but the propsed solutions do not resolve my issue.

I have a solution that builds fine within the VS2010 IDE, when I build using Team Build/MSBuild I get the following error:

**The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

In reading other posts on this same error message, I have done the following:

1. Verified that the reference **is** there in the project - listed in .csproj file as well as listed under the references in the project located in the solution file.
2. Verified .NET framework is the same (v4.0) for all projects in solution
3. Added reference to System.Data.Entity
4. Verified .NET Framework is NOT listed as "Client Profile"
5. Verified that **System.Data** resides on the build server under C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

A little history - this is a new build that I am setting up, it is a C# web application, has a Silverlight project in it and also has a project that shares code with another project. I am not the developer of this web app, just the Configuration Manager trying to get this thing to build.

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.Data.Entities as well and is the installed version of the enity framework the same on the buildserver as your local workstation ?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I am getting the same problem...

Comment: have you logged onto the build server and checked that you can build it in VS on there?